# New Line \n Does Not Work in MongoDB Atlas

Tags: html, json, mongodb, pug, mongodb-atlas

I've stored a document with a string field in MongoDB Atlas that I use to populate to an HTML (pug) element. I want to indicate a new line in the text using the escape \n. However, the character does not perform the escape and populates the '\n' with the text in HTML, instead of starting a new line of text.

JSON in Mongodb Atlas

```
{
 "mystring" : "I want this to be two lines. \n Two lines would be great"
}
```

PUG code:

```
p!= data.mystring
```

Renders in HTML as:

```
I want this to be two lines. \n Two lines would be great
```

Desired Render in HTML:

```
I want this to be two lines.
Two lines would be great
```

FWIW, this worked just fine when I was hosting on MLab.  But, we're forced to migrate to Atlas and the same \n escape doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try replacing `\n` with `br`.

Comment: `br` didn't work, but `<br>` did work. I'll have to change a lot of data and account for this in CSS.  I may not have any other choice.  I just don't understand why Atlas won't recognize a legit escape in this scenario.

Comment: Atlas / mLab should not have anything to do with that, are you sure you haven't changed anything in css? `\n` in HTML are usually not rendered as new line unless you apply the style `whitespace: pre-line` or something else with the same behaviour

Comment: Use `mongo` shell to find out what the server stores, so that you know whether this is a persistence or query issue.

Comment: @thammada.ts  I do have `white-space: pre-line;` set in CSS.  I also tried `white-space: pre-wrap;` thinking that was the problem, but no luck.

Comment: @D. SM   To your point, it seems that `\n` comes back as `\\n` which kinda explains what is happening.  I just don't know how to work around this.  I do appreciate all the suggestions here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In response to your comment that the `\n` is coming from the database already escaped (`\\n`), you could use regex within Pug to unescape it:

```
- let mystring = 'I want this to be two lines. \\n Two lines would be great'

p!= mystring.replace(/\\n/g, '\n')
```

This will compile to:

```html
<p>I want this to be two lines.
Two lines would be great</p>
```

However, as you can see in this stack snippet, HTML collapses whitespace characters, so it won't be rendered in multiple lines in a browser.

```html
<p>I want this to be two lines.
Two lines would be great</p>
```

---

To make the HTML render the line breaks, you need to use a `<br>` element, as @isAif pointed out.

You could insert this via regex in Pug as well:

```
- let mystring = 'I want this to be two lines. \\n Two lines would be great'

p!= mystring.replace(/\\n/g, '<br>\n')
```

This will compile to:

```html
<p>I want this to be two lines.<br>
Two lines would be great</p>
```

Which will render the line break in browsers, as illustrated below.

```html
<p>I want this to be two lines.<br>
Two lines would be great</p>
```

Comment: This only replaces the first instance of `\\n`. But, I learned about the global modifier.  I used `.replace(/\\n/g,'\n')` and it worked for all instances within the string.  I updated this in the controller, instead of the pug view.  It still doesn't explain why the escape behaves this way in Atlas, but this workaround gets me going again.